# JSON of object of type Any and a TypeTag

Tags: scala, shapeless, argonaut, argonaut-shapeless

Given an object of type Any and its TypeTag, how can Argonaut/Shapeless be used to create JSON of it?

```
  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  // somewhere in the code where type of 'any' is known,
  // and we preferrably dont want to include information
  // about JSON capabilities (i.e. prefer not to include
  // implicit EncodeJson[Person])
  val tt = typeTag[Person].asInstanceOf[TypeTag[Any]]
  val any = Person("myname", 123).asInstanceOf[Any]

  //somewhere else in the code where type of 'any' is unknown, but we got the TypeTag 'tt'
  implicit val e: EncodeJson[ ??? ] = ??? //somehow utilize 'tt' here?
  println(any.asJson)
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using reflection, i.e. with compile-time type safety. As soon as you cast the type tag to `TypeTag[Any]`, the compiler can't use it anymore to resolve the implicit `EncodeJson` value. If you want to decouple the JSON encoding from your domain objects, you could consider using type classes. But as soon as you cast your domain object to `Any` you will be lost in any case, you could maybe use a match/case statement to select the `EncodeJson` val for your object based on the runtime type.

Comment: I see. Was hoping to avoid that. How about if one does accept some degree of reflection, how would one get an instance of an appropriate EncodeJson? I'm thinking about ArgonautShapeless 'EncodeJson.of[T]', but I cant figure out if it's applicable at runtime.

Comment: After a bit more research it looks like it is impossible to resolve implicit parameters at runtime. There is `toolbox.inferImplicitValue` (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/ta-vbUT6JE8%5B1-25%5D), but I don't think this helps either. I would recommend to preserve the `EncodeJson` information for the object.

Comment: @devkat following your advice. If you post your finds in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without using reflection, i.e. with compile-time type safety. As soon as you cast the type tag to `TypeTag[Any]`, the compiler can't use it anymore to resolve the implicit `EncodeJson` value. As far as I know it is impossible to resolve implicit parameters at runtime. There is [`toolbox.inferImplicitValue`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/ta-vbUT6JE8%5B1-25%5D), but I don't think this helps either.

If you know all possible types, you could maybe use a match/case statement to select the `EncodeJson` val for your object based on the runtime type, and pass it explicitly.

I would recommend to preserve the `EncodeJson` information for the object, though.